# How to set the "-jN" argument to "ndk-build" in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

Using "ndk-build -jN" can speed up android ndk builds(command line), but how to do in Android Studio? somebody help?????

Comment: How about `externalNativeBuild { ndkBuild { arguments "-j4" } }` ? (replace `ndkBuild` with `cmake` if that's what you use).

Comment: yeah,it works!!  android { externalNativeBuild {ndkBuild { arguments "-j4" thanks!!!!